# How can I compare these three variables in PHP

Tags: php

I'm trying to compare these three conditions, I need it to not be empty, but be between minus 180 and positive 180, the requests function when its above 180 however not when below. Also reguardless of bad requests the information is still inputted to the database. Any ideas?

Line I need help with:

```
    if(($lat == "") && ($lat < $minval) || ($lat > $maxval)){
        header('HTTP/1.1 400 Bad Request');
    }
```

The full code is available here

http://pastebin.com/gt8QnUWh

Thanks in advance

Comment: you need to call `exit;` or `die` after setting the response code

Comment: also there is a function for setting response codes, you don't need to use `header` http://php.net/manual/en/function.http-response-code.php

Comment: if(empty($lat) && ($lat < $minval) && ($lat > $maxval)){
        header('HTTP/1.1 400 Bad Request');
   }

Comment: The first `&&` ought to be `||` -- if it is empty OR it is less than the min OR if it is greater than the max...  And then apply the `exit();` after `header()` as suggested.

Comment: Thank you for the extremely fast responses, edits have been made and the code is now fully functional! Thanks everyone

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You mixed up your operators, and their preference too. Do this:

```
if(empty($lat) || ($lat < $minval) || ($lat > $maxval)) {
  header('HTTP/1.1 400 Bad Request');
  //As suggested in the comments, you could also add this 
  exit();
}
```